# Как принудительно очистить память

Tags: php

Требуется выгрузить порядка 50 тысяч строк из базы в Excel-файл. Доступно 1 ГБ оперативки. Загружаю в цикле 5 раз 10 тысяч (опытным путём установлено, что это около 500мб данных) в переменную $records. В конце цикла делаю unset($records);

На 2-ом цикле у меня

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted
```

gc_enabled включен, а memory_get_usage показывает, что после память после каждого прохода цикла только растёт на +500. GC не хочет работать.
Как мне очистить память? Как мне загрузить большой объем данных при низких возможностях ОЗУ?

Comment: Этот комментарий https://habrahabr.ru/post/245233/#comment_8169305 наверняка про ваш случай.

Comment: А создаваемый файл случайно в памяти не хранится?

Answer (score 0):

> Как мне очистить память?

`gc_collect_cycles` — Принудительный запуск сборщика мусора.

Явным образом запускает механизм поиска циклических ссылок.

Возвращает число найденных ссылок.

Источник: [gc_collect_cycles()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)

Comment: gc_collect_cycles() возвращает 0.